# Complete previous execution of the callback before its next invocation

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback

I have a callback function written something like this.

```
callbackFn = (): Promise<void> => {
    if ('condition 1') {
        await doA();
    }
    else {
        await doB();
    }
}
```

```
doB = (): Promise<void> => {
// Do something 
// other await calls
    await doA();
}
```

```
doA = (): Promise<void> => {
    // Do something
}
```

On the client side, this callbackFn is registered with model so that it can be invoked on model update.

```
    onModelUpdate(callbackFn: () => void): void {
        this.on(modelUpdateEvent, callbackFn);
    }
```

During the first instance of callback invocation from model, else flow gets executed. While the next callback invocation excutes the if part.

However during the execution, doA() originating from if part gets executed first instead of doA() originating from doB(). How do I ensure that my firstcallback execution gets completed before the second one?

I am expecting that the order of callback execution is preserved but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that can be run directly to see the issue. For one thing, your definition of `callbackFn` is invalid syntax.

Comment: I have tried to add some more details to clarify however I am not able to explain it any better right now. Pardon me for this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a queue and inside the `callbackFn` add tasks to that queue instead of directly executing them.

Comment: neither your callback or named function are async so await has not effect (and shouldn't even be usable without error)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You should study event loops in JS (see the Node.JS event loop explanation [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick#what-is-the-event-loop)).

What is important is that when you run code containing a callback (start a Promise with a .then(), use a timer, or pass around a callback, like your model update event), that callback will be *scheduled* to run at a future time. For instance, when your `onModelUpdate()` method executes, it creates a callback in memory that will be *scheduled* to execute whenever the event fires.

That scheduled execution happens at particular times in the event loop lifecycle, depending on factors like what type of callback it is. In Node.JS, your `callbackFn()` will be scheduled to execute in the "pending callbacks" queue, which is separate from the "timers" and "close callbacks" queues, and will execute when the event loop reaches that part of the cycle and the queue in front of it has drained.

If that callback calls an await (starts execution of a Promise, which contains a callback, just like your `onModelUpdate()` function does), a *separate* callback will be scheduled, *after the Promise resolves*.

In the meantime, the event loop has likely cycled many times and other code is executing, scheduling many other callbacks to execute in different queues. You cannot expect the Promise to resolve after some other action, just because it was started after the first action - and that's especially not going to happen if the first action has several execute+schedule callback cycles to go through.

If you need these to execute in a certain order, you can't trigger them both asynchronously without additional complexity. You may need to rearchitect the application.

If one process is truly dependent on another to execute first, they must be written synchronously or you must specifically schedule them in order, by chaining callbacks, chaining Promises, using a separate queue, message queue + polling, "mutexes", or other means.